# how do I set up a cloudflare failover without having control of their DNS?

Tags: dns, cloudflare, amazon-aws, dynamic-dns

I'm trying to use Cloudflare's fail-over system, but I won't be able to transfer the domain's DNS to Cloudflare. The owner of the domain has offered to set up a CNAME but I don't know how that would help, because the site will be hosted under the root domain, not a subdomain.

I'm going to host the site on an AWS server, and I plan to keep a copy of it on a backup VPS at another provider like Vultr, and I would like Cloudflare to be able to do a DNS failover per their offering. Can this be done if I can't bring the DNS into a Cloudflare account? Are there other good ways to set up a failover mechanism without having direct access to the DNS?

Thanks

Comment: They'll need to add their domain to a Cloudflare account and use their nameservers in order to use their [load balancing & failover service](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000081911-Tutorial-How-to-Set-Up-Load-Balancing-Intelligent-Failover-on-Cloudflare) (which is $5 per month). They can create the account themselves if they want to maintain control over their DNS (by default all the same DNS records are retained, only the nameservers change). Then you can guide them on how to add the service and the second IP of the VPS to use, or they can add you as an account user.

Comment: The owner can not benefit from Cloudflare if he/she is unwilling to change name servers, fact, no-work-around.